Issue with Xamarin.Android.Google.BillingClient - Returning Empty Product List in .NET 8 MAUI
I am currently using .NET 8 with Xamarin.Android.Google.BillingClient version 7.1.1 in my MAUI application. When attempting to retrieve product details from the Google Play Store, the BillingClient returns a successful response (BillingResponseCode.Ok), but the list of products is empty.
Steps Taken

Verified that product IDs are correctly set up in the Google Play

Console. Checked for any network or connectivity issues.


Used the following code to call QueryProductDetails and handle the response.
public void OnProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult p0, IList<ProductDetails> p1)
{
    if (p0.ResponseCode == BillingResponseCode.Ok)
    {
        // Handle successful response, but p1 is empty
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle error case
    }
}

public void querySKUDetails()
{
    if (!billingClient.IsReady)
    {
        return;
    }
    ImmutableList<Product> productList = ImmutableList.Create(Product.NewBuilder()
                                    .SetProductId("productid")
                                    .SetProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.Subs)
                                    .Build());    
    var paramse = QueryProductDetailsParams.NewBuilder().SetProductList(productList).Build();
    billingClient.QueryProductDetails(paramse, this);
}

Questions

Compatibility Issue: Could this issue be due to compatibility between
Xamarin.Android.Google.BillingClient 7.1.1 and .NET 8 MAUI?
Known Issues: Are there any known issues with this package version that could cause an empty product list response?
Alternative Solutions: If this package version has issues, are there alternative ways to reliably fetch product details from the Play Store in MAUI?

